# how to call amount in the method

Tags: python, methods, tkinter

```
# Tip Calculator
from tkinter import *

class TipCalc:
    def __init__(self):
        my_window = Tk() # create a window
        my_window.title("Tip Calculator")
        my_window.geometry('400x200')

        amount = StringVar()

        # create frames labels, entry, and buttons
        frm_upper = Frame(my_window)
        frm_upper.pack()
        frm_mid = Frame(my_window)
        frm_mid.pack()
        frm_lower = Frame(my_window)
        frm_lower.pack()

        # create label and entry for amount
        amount_label = Label(frm_upper, text = "Enter Amount: ")
        my_entry = Entry(frm_upper, textvariable = amount)
        my_entry.delete(0, END)
        my_entry.insert(0, "")

        # create a label for total amount
        total_label = Label(frm_mid, text = "")

        # create buttons in lower frame
        btn_10_perc = Button(frm_lower, text = "10%", command = self.calculate_10_perc)
        btn_15_perc = Button(frm_lower, text = "15%", command = self.calculate_15_perc)
        btn_18_perc = Button(frm_lower, text = "18%", command = self.calculate_18_perc)
        btn_20_perc = Button(frm_lower, text = "20%", command = self.calculate_20_perc)

        amount_label. grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        my_entry.    grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        btn_10_perc. grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        btn_15_perc. grid(row = 3, column = 2)
        btn_18_perc. grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        btn_20_perc. grid(row = 3, column = 4)

        my_window.mainloop()

    def calculate_10_perc(self):
        bill = float(self.amount.get())
        total = bill*1.10
        total_result = Label(frm_mid, "Total after tip added: %.2f" % total).grid(row=2, column =1)
        return

    def calculate_15_perc(self):
        pass

    def calculate_18_perc(self):
        pass

    def calculate_20_perc(self):
        pass


########################### Main Program ###############################
TipCalc() # anonymous instance of the class
```

How do I call the amount in the instance into the method so i can use it to calculate?  I'm getting an error,

> AttributeError: 'TipCalc' object has no attribute 'amount'

Comment: Please do not replace your original code with the updated code, as otherwise neither your error not any of the below answers make any sense anymore. Rolling back to previous version. BTW, you forgot the `()` after `self.total_label.pack`, otherwise it seems to run fine now.

Comment: im getting File "C:\Python34\tip calculator.py", line 47, in calculate_perc
    bill = float(self.amount.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:               

when i press the button

Comment: Well, what did you enter into the textfield? It seems like there's still the empty string in the input field.

Comment: thanks, everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

You have to bind `amount` to `self`, i.e.

```
amount = StringVar()
```

should be

```
self.amount = StringVar()
```

Accordingly, you also have to change `my_entry = Entry(frm_upper, textvariable=amount)` to `my_entry = Entry(frm_upper, textvariable=self.amount)`

Otherwise, `self.amount` is not defined when you do `bill = float(self.amount.get())` in `calculate_10_perc`.

---

Also, note that doing

```
total_result = Label(...).grid(row=2, column=1)
```

`total_result` is *not* the `Label` but the result of `grid`, i.e. `None`

It seems like you are (trying to) create a new label each time you update the `total` value. Instead, you should `configure` the existing label to hold the new value. in `__init__`:

```
self.total_label = Label(frm_mid, text="")
self.total_label.pack()
```

And in `calculate_10_perc`:

```
self.total_label.configure(text="Total after tip added: %.2f" % total)
```

---

Finally, given that all those `calculate_X_perc` functions will probably look very similar, you could make it one function and pass the percent as a parameter, e.g. in `__init__`:

```
btn_10_perc = Button(frm_lower, text = "10%", command=lambda: self.calculate_perc(1.1))
```

And the function:

```
def calculate_perc(self, percent):
    bill = float(self.amount.get())
    self.total_label.configure(text="Total after tip added: %.2f" % (bill * percent))
```

Comment: when i add the self, it says amount is then not defined

Comment: Could you update your code in the question to what you have now?

Comment: so what goes where? i dont understand

Comment: im trying to make it so that, it has the entry and then when i click a button it calculates the entry multiplied with the button % i clicked then output it with a label

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the issue here is that you're not making `amount` an instance variable in `__init__`:

```
class TipCalc:
    def __init__(self):
        my_window = Tk() # create a window
        my_window.title("Tip Calculator")
        my_window.geometry('400x200')

        amount = StringVar()
        ...
```

Notice that you're simply declaring `amount`, not `self.amount`. This means that `amount` is a normal variable in `__init__` that disappears when `__init__` finishes, not an instance variable that lives as long as the instance exists.

Then you're getting your error here:

```
def calculate_10_perc(self):
    bill = float(self.amount.get())
```

Because `self.amount` isn't a thing at this point - `amount` disappeared when `__init__` finished.

So probably the easiest solution is to simply change `__init__` and make `amount` an instance variable:

```
class TipCalc:
    def __init__(self):
        my_window = Tk() # create a window
        my_window.title("Tip Calculator")
        my_window.geometry('400x200')

        self.amount = StringVar()
        ...
```

Then, **be sure to replace all the references to `amount` with `self.amount`.**